# v-data-table search in expand slot

Tags: vuetify.js

Is it even possible to search in expand slot in v-data-table?
According to my test below it doesn't work, try to search expandData property in items

```
<template slot="expand" slot-scope="props">
    {{ props.item.expandData }}
</template>
```

[codepen test](https://codepen.io/acharkov/pen/LrvYbW)

What should I look further for next step in case if need this kind of search for my project?

Thanks in advance